# Branch points of $z^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, branch-cuts

The function $z^n$ pass $n$ times by the same point in the complex plane of the codomain, if $f(z)=z^n$, each $z_n=\sqrt[n]{r}.e^{i.(\frac{\theta}{n}+\frac{2.\pi}{n})}$ has the same image (right?), so the branch cuts that I should take to make this function injective is $\alpha\lt arg(z)\lt\alpha+\frac{2.\pi}{n}$?

Comment: Yes but the word branch cut applies to $z^{1/n}$, the restriction of $z^n$ to a domain where it is injective/biholomorphic has no name.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this.